# Passing char array from ObjC to C

Tags: objective-c, c

I've got a project with a pure c code and c code handled by the ObjC compiler [`.m file`]. The one handled by ObjC compiler has a following class:

```
unsigned long getMessage(char ** message) {
 *message = (char*)calloc(1, [dMessage bytes], [dMessage length]);
 memcpy(message, [dMessage bytes], [dMessage length])
return [dMessage length];
}
```

`dMessage` is an `NSData` object filled with text.

On C side, I do:

```
char* msg = NULL
unsigned long length = getMessage(&msg)
```

After the call, `msg` is empty, but the length variable is set to correct size.

What should I do to pass `char*` between objc and c?

Thank you

Comment: What is `getMessage` really doing?  The data is already allocated in the `NSData` object so just keep it around and access the raw bytes via `[dMessage bytes]`.

Comment: It's a function written in C, accessing some data which is stored in database, which I access usinc ObjC Library and code. I have to pass it on to a library written in pure C and I don't want to change that lib, want to keep it as close to original as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake in my code.

I should havecalled

`memcpy(*message, [dMessage bytes], [dMessage length])`

instead of

`memcpy(message, [dMessage bytes], [dMessage length])`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong arguments to `calloc()`. It takes two arguments, but you're passing three. The compiler should be screaming at you about that.

Since the second argument is the `bytes` pointer from the `NSData`, you're effectively requesting some huge allocation. It's probably failing. There would usually be a message logged to the console about that failure.

You want:

```
*message = (char*)calloc([dMessage length], 1);
```

Comment: Hmm no, there's no message, code compiles and "runs", but doesn't work. The code you proposed didn't solve it.